# how to remove polyline path from source to current position while moving

Tags: android, google-maps

i want to remove the previous polyline while moving, i am using the GoogleDirection class to draw the polyline. please refer below code snippet

```
   GoogleDirection.withServerKey(getResources().getString(R.string.google_maps_key))
                .from(origin)
                .to(destination)
                .transportMode(TransportMode.DRIVING)
                .alternativeRoute(true)
                .execute(this);

 @Override
public void onDirectionSuccess(Direction direction, String rawBody) {   
            mMap.clear();
            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(destination));
            ArrayList<LatLng> directionPositionList = direction.getRouteList().get(0).getLegList().get(0).getDirectionPoint();
            polyline = mMap.addPolyline(DirectionConverter.createPolyline(this, directionPositionList, 3, Color.BLACK));

}
  @Override
public void onDirectionFailure(Throwable t) {
    Log.e("Direction fail Sorry", " no route found for this location.");
```

[image]
    }

Please refer screenshot, need to update polyline according to current location.

Comment: did you find a solution?

Answer (score 3):

You can test for each polyline segment for current position on the polyline segment laying with  [Google Maps Android API Utility Library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/utility/) namely [`PolyUtil.containsLocation(LatLng point, java.util.List<LatLng> polygon, boolean geodesic)`](http://googlemaps.github.io/android-maps-utils/javadoc/com/google/maps/android/PolyUtil.html#containsLocation-LatLng-java.util.List-boolean-).

```
...
int ixLastPoint = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < path.getPoints().length; i++) {
    LatLng point1 = path.getPoints().get(i);
    LatLng point2 = path.getPoints().get(i);
    List<LatLng> currentSegment = new ArrayList<>();
    currentSegment.add(point1);
    currentSegment.add(point2);
    if (PolyUtil.isLocationOnPath(currentLocation, currentSegment, true, 50)) {
        // save index of last point and exit loop
        ixLastPoint = i;
        break;
    }
}
...
```

And than delete points from path from `0` to `ixLastPoint` like that way:

```
...
List<LatLng> pathPoints = path.getPoints();
for (int i = 0; i < ixLastPoint; i++) {
    pathPoints.remove(0);
}
path.setPoints(pathPoints);
...
```

NB! This is just approach, not complete solution.

Comment: path is you PolylineOptions or Polyline?

Comment: @Andrii Omelchenko why did you add the same point twice to currentSegment (`point1` & `point2`) ?

Comment: @BhavinChauhan did you find related solution? i know it's been a year, sorry

Comment: @Fidel I know same point use twice but magic is that Andrii full code work for me thanks Andrii

Comment: He mentioned about containsLocation, but he use isLocationPath instead. this leads to ambiguous for the solution seeker.

Comment: @Fidel yes but isLocationOnPath is working good. Did you tried this code or not? what's the problem in your code share snippet so we can help you

Answer (score 2):

To remove a polyline you should simply use remove() method

```
//Add line to map
Polyline confirmPathPlotLine= mMap.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions()
            .add(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()),
                    new LatLng(this.destinationLatitude, this.destinationLongitude))
            .width(1)
            .color(Color.DKGRAY)

//Remove the same line from map
confirmPathPlotLine.remove();
```

Answer (score -1):

Use you **Current location** as your **Origin**. then everytime **onLocationChange** gives you **location** **clear** the **map**, and request new Route under Direction API. everytime you request for new location it also request new Route.

Comment: solution will work but It will request path so many times and it is bad manner as per my knowledge